# How to send an azure queued message to an azure sql database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have set up an ASP.NET C# application that sends information to an azure storage account queue. Next l need to send the message text from within the queue to an azure sql database via means of a function.
Format of the message text is as follows:

Id:VaccinationCenter:VaccinationDate:VaccineSerialNumber

E.g. 010203040506:Dubai:01/01/2002:AASB44

The table is created within Azure Database and contains the following columns: ID, Vaccination_Centre, Vaccination_Date, Vaccine_Serial_Number
Any ideas how to achive this? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an Azure Function with a [Queue Trigger Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger) and a [SQL Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-output).

Comment: Trey is correct, that's the easiest way in my opinion

Comment: If not required to be an Azure function could use a Logic App.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Mildenberger commented we can alternatively use Azure Logic Apps to perform your requirement as below:
Firstly, I have created a service bus queue as below:

[image]

Then create Logic App
Then inside the workflow of the Logic App:
Firstly, create a trigger when a new message comes inside the service bus queue as below:
[image]

The the queue messafe to string using `base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])`  as  below:

[image]

Then split the queue message using `split(variables('emo'),':')` as below:

[image]

Then you can message to Sql Databse table using (Sql connector) create row as below:

[image]

[image]

For **id** its `variables('div')[0]`
**VaccinationCenter** its `variables('div')[1]`
**vaccinationdate** its `variables('div')[2]`
and **VaccineSerialNumber** it is `variables('div')[3]`

Then now send the message in Service bus queue as below:

[image]

Now time to check the run result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now its also in Sql database table:

[image]

If you follow this process, you will get your row inserted as mine got inserted.